# Tailwind custom forms: how to add your own color (hex value)

Tags: tailwind-css

This site: https://tailwindcss-custom-forms.netlify.app/ gives this example `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    customForms: theme => ({
      dark: {
        'input, textarea, multiselect, checkbox, radio': {
          backgroundColor: theme('colors.gray.900'),
        },
        select: {
          backgroundColor: theme('colors.gray.600'),
        },
      },
      sm: {
        'input, textarea, multiselect, select': {
          fontSize: theme('fontSize.sm'),
          padding: `${theme('spacing.1')} ${theme('spacing.2')}`,
        },
        select: {
          paddingRight: `${theme('spacing.4')}`,
        },
        'checkbox, radio': {
          width: theme('spacing.3'),
          height: theme('spacing.3'),
        },
      }
    })
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/custom-forms'),
  ]
}
```

it uses `colors.gray.600` notation for setting colors. However I need a `#f90f39` color. How do I set it?

Answer (score 13):

Use Tailwind’s arbitrary value notation to generate a class for that color on-demand instead of adding it to your theme

```
<button class="bg-[#1da1f2] text-white ..."></button>
```

But the best way to use a custom color is to define in your theme **tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      'myColor': '#1da1f2'
    },
  },
}
```

Now use it everywhere in your project.

```
<button class="bg-myColor text-white ..."></button>
```

Comment: This seems to only work with colors that were actually defined in the `custom.colors` section of your `tailwind.config.js`. Use inline-style if you want truly custom colors.

Answer (score 0):

You need customize colors in `tailwind.config.js`: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#app